# Implementar funcionalidade Seguir/Deixar de Seguir

Tags: php, sql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de seguidores, criei uma página que faz uma busca de usuários registrados. Você digita em um input um nome, e ele verifica se tem algum registro com esse nome no banco de dados.

Coloquei do lado de cada nome que retorna do banco de dados, um botão "**Seguir**" para caso a pessoa queira seguir o usuário. Porém, quero também que caso a pessoa já tenha seguido aquele usuário, não apareça o botão de seguir, mas sim, o botão de "**Deixar de Seguir**".

Criei o botão e adicionei na página, tentei implementar sozinho mas não consegui, então me indicaram fazer um SELECT de todos os usuários, salvar isso em um array, e depois em um loop, verificar com o `in_array()` se a pessoa que está logada, já seguiu o usuário que retornou da busca, mas não consegui fazer funciona! A query busca está funcionando corretamente, onde estou errando?

Função **SELECT**:

```
<?php

    include 'fconnect.php';
    include 'fdesconnect.php';

    function select($tabela,$coluna="*",$where=NULL,$ordem=NULL,$limite=NULL) {

        // Query de consulta
        $sql= "SELECT {$coluna} FROM {$tabela} {$where} {$ordem} {$limite}";

        // conectou?

        if($conexao= connect()) {

            // Conseguiu consultar?
            if($query= mysql_query($sql,$conexao)) {
                // Encontrou algo?
                if (mysql_num_rows($query)>0) {

                    $resultados_totais = array();
                    while ($resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                        $resultados_totais[] = $resultado;
                    }

                    // Fecha conexão
                    desconnect($conexao);

                    return $resultados_totais;
                }else{
                    return false;
                } 
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

Página que realizo a busca e mostra os botões, deixei apenas as partes essenciais.

```
$idsession = $_SESSION['ID'];
$consulta2 = select("u636623377_users", "*", "WHERE fname LIKE '%$q%'");
$consulta3 = select("u636623377_follows", "idfollowed", "WHERE idfollower = '$idsession'");

<div class="box">
                            <div class="box-header">
                                <h3 class="box-title">Resultado da Busca...</h3>
                            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                            <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                                <table class="table table-hover">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Usuário</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th>Cidade</th>
                                        <th>Estado</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php if($consulta2 == true){
                                    for ($i=0;$i<count($consulta2);$i++) {

                                        $idatual = $consulta2[$i]['id'];
                                ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><img class="img-circle" src="assets/img/img_profile/<?php echo $consulta2[$i]['photoperf'] ?>" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;"></td>
                                        <td><h4 style="font-family:'Asap',sans-serif;"><?php echo $consulta2[$i]['fname'] ?></h4></td>
                                        <td><h4 style="font-family:'Asap',sans-serif;"><?php echo $consulta2[$i]['city'] ?></h4></td>
                                        <td><h4 style="font-family:'Asap',sans-serif;"><?php echo $consulta2[$i]['state'] ?></h4></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <h4 style="font-family:'Asap',sans-serif;">
                                                <a href="profile.php?link=<?php echo $consulta2[$i]['profile'] ?>" class="label label-primary">Ver Perfil</a>

                                                <?php if($consulta2[$i]['id'] == $_SESSION['ID']){}else{ ?>

                                                <?php if(in_array($idatual, $consulta3)){ ?>
                                                <a href="php/scripts/disfollow.php?id=<?php echo $consulta2[$i]['id'] ?>" class="label label-danger">Deixar de Seguir</a>
                                                <?php }else{ ?>
                                                <a href="php/scripts/follow.php?id=<?php echo $consulta2[$i]['id'] ?>" class="label label-success">Seguir</a>
                                                <?php } } ?>
                                            </h4>
                                        </td>   
                                    </tr>
                                <?php } } ?>
                                </table>
                            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                        </div><!-- /.box -->
```

- **$consulta2** é o que busca os usuários no banco de dados.
- **$consulta3** é o que busca todos os usuários que a pessoa logada segue.

`var_dump` na variável **$consulta3**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: Essa é a estrutura da tabela dos usuários]

[image: Essa [é a estrutura da tabela das "seguidas"]

- **idfollower** é o id da pessoa que seguiu.
- **idfollowed** é o id da pessoa que foi seguida.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que existe uma maneira bem mais fácil de resolver o problema.

## Solução 1:

Substitua a linha:

```
if(in_array($idatual, $consulta3)){
```

Por:

```
if(in_array($idatual, $consulta3['idfollowed'])){
```

- Ideia: o in_array deveria ser para o idfollowed, já que é ele que contem o idsession.

## Solução 2:

**Etapa 1: Primeiro altere o $consulta3:**

Vamos lá, substitua a linha:

```
$consulta3 = select("u636623377_follows", "idfollowed", "WHERE idfollower = '$idsession'");
```

Por:

```
$consulta3 = select("u636623377_follows", "idfollowed", "WHERE idfollower = '$idsession' AND idfollowed = '$consulta2['id']'");
```

- Ideia: Ele irá selecionar o que tiver o idfollower igual à sessão atual e também tiver o idfollowed igual ao id do perfil que está vendo.

Então,  em seu `SELECT()` retorna `false` se o `mysql_num_rows` for igual à 0. Logo, se não encontrar o `$consulta3` será `false`, perfeito.

**Etapa 2: Altere o if Deixar de seguir:**

Substitua a linha:

```
<?php if(in_array($idatual, $consulta3)){ ?>
```

Por:

```
<?php if($consulta3){ ?>
```

- Ideia: Se o $consulta for false ele irá exibir 'Seguir', se não irá exibir 'Deixar de seguir'.

## Solução (pós-var_dump):

Utilize loop:

```
<? $total = count($consulta3);
    for($i =0; $i < $total; $i++){
       if($consulta3[$i]['followed'] == $idatual){ ?>

           <a href="php/scripts/disfollow.php?id=<?php echo $consulta2[$i]['id'] ?>" class="label label-danger">Deixar de Seguir</a>
       <?php }else{ ?>
           <a href="php/scripts/follow.php?id=<?php echo $consulta2[$i]['id'] ?>" class="label label-success">Seguir</a>
       <? } 
    } ?>
```

Seria uma solução, ou utilizar o `foreach`, mas, seguiria a mesma logica.

Comment: Infelizmente, nenhuma das duas funcionou... :c

Comment: Atualizei depois do var_dump.